# foreach only outputting last run query by date

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently working on a small production tracker to make my life easier at work, all going well so far but i'm hitting a wall when it comes to getting some statistics.

I'm trying to count all rows with monday-sundays dates and between certain hours to denote day/night shifts.

Below is what I have so far, the issue I'm having is the only query that seems to be working is Days and even that seems to only want to output Sundays (today) count, everything else is coming back as 0. echoing the $key or $value foreach comes out correct though.

Thanks for any help.

```
$this_week = array($monday=>"monday", $tuesday=>"tuesday", $wednesday=>"wednesday", $thursday=>"thursday", $friday=>"friday", $saturday=>"saturday", $sunday=>"sunday");

foreach ($this_week as $key => $value) {

// Days

$sql_day = "SELECT count(*) FROM `stage_tbl` WHERE stage_1_date = :datenow AND stage_1_time BETWEEN :day_start AND :day_end"; 
$result_day = $conn->prepare($sql_day); 
$result_day->execute(array ('datenow' => $key, 'day_start' => $day_start, 'day_end' => $day_end)); 
$number_of_rows_day = $result_day->fetchColumn();

$day = "{$value}_day";

$$day = $number_of_rows_day;


// Nights

$datenext = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($key. ' + 1 days'));

$sql_night = "SELECT count(*) FROM `stage_tbl` WHERE stage_1_date = :datenow AND stage_1_time >= :night_start OR WHERE stage_1_date = :datenext AND stage_1_time <= :night_end"; 
$result_night = $conn->prepare($sql_night); 
$result_night->execute(array ('datenow' => $key, 'night_start' => $night_start, 'night_end' => $night_end, 'datenext' => $datenext)); 
$number_of_rows_night = $result_night->fetchColumn();

$night = "{$value}_night";

$$night = $number_of_rows_night;

}
```

Comment: Why mysql stuff is involved at all in this array related question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the variable $monday till $sunday keys. You are not assigning these variables.

What you would want is this:

```
$this_week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
```

Notice that we also don't use the older array() syntax anymore to create an array. Nowadays we use the [] syntax.

Now we can loop through:

```
foreach ($this_week as $day) {

// your logic goes here
// $day will equal 'Monday' for the first run 
// and 'Sunday' for the last run

}
```

Comment: Making this change has allowed me to clean things up a little but I'm still having the exact same issue. Only the last day seems to be being counted although there are many entries with the other dates.

Answer (score 0):

I was not putting the output within the foreach so in the end i was only getting the last result. Thanks for looking though.